# Find Total number of connected players based on variant in RealTime multiplayer Game in GPGS

Tags: android, multiplayer

I am using Google Play Gaming Services for Variant based Real time Multiplayer game,

I am setting variant for the room user wants to play the game as follows

```
RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
rtmConfigBuilder.setVariant(getVariantRoomCode(true));//setting variant here
rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
```

- I want to find out the total number of users playing the game, room wise
  Ex.
- In Room 1 connected player count can be 100
- In Room 2 connected player count can be 45 etc.

I know that the following way gives total count of connected players, but i want it variant wise

```
connectedPlayers=Games.Players.loadConnectedPlayers(mGoogleApiClient,true);
        connectedPlayers.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Players.LoadPlayersResult>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onResult(Players.LoadPlayersResult result) {
                PlayerBuffer buf = result.getPlayers();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "players"+buf.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Any help is highly appreciated, Thanks